# BigQuery - Error while reading table:Could not convert value to date. Error: Invalid date:

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to read a Google Sheet in BQ. After selecting auto-detect schema, I get this error on trying to run the query. I'm not sure what do I need to adjust in the date schema to make the query work.

SELECT date FROM `proejct.dataset.table` LIMIT 1000

Sharing the error and two screenshots from the query

Error while reading table: project.dataset.table, error message: Could not convert value to date. Error: Invalid date: '1/15/2011'. Row 1; Col 2.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format `YYYY-MM-DD` should work for you

```sql
select DATE "2021-1-1"
```

Comment: Hi Zhang, did you mean changing the schema or the data in Google sheet?

Comment: Either one, you can either change table schema DATE -> STRING or data in Sheet '1/15/2011' -> '2011-1-15'

Comment: Hi Zhang, if former, should the revised query be: SELECT date "2021-1-1" FROM project.dataset.table ? I tried it but it didn't work. Also, why wouldn't BQ be able to read m/d/yyyy format?

Comment: If you keep the data type as "String" then at query time you will be able to use PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y',string_column) to parse you m/d/yyyy. But when you query data from external source (in your case, Google Sheet), you don't get to specify what date format is desirable to you

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to explain, Zhang. I appreciate it. Query now works.